# Plotting crosses on a graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering how you would plot crosses at certain points on a graph using TikZ. I have managed to plot circles using the code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,dotted] (-5.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,1.9);
\draw[semithick] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[semithick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

\foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}
    \draw (\x cm, 1.5pt) -- (\x cm, -1.5pt) node[anchor=north] {\scriptsize $\x$};
\fill [radius=2.5pt,color=blue] (-5.2,0) circle[] (-4.2,0) circle[] (-3.2,0) circle[] (-2.2,0) circle[] (-1.2,0) circle[] (-0.2,0) circle;
\fill [radius=2.5pt,color=red] (0.1,0) circle[] (1.1,0) circle[] (2.1,0) circle[] (3.1,0) circle[] (4.1,0) circle[] (5.1,0) circle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(I'm sure there is a much simpler way but I am new to TikZ) however, I have not been able to do something similar with crosses.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also, check out page 332 of the manual.

Answer (score 4):

An option using `pic`s:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
  mycross/.pic={
    \draw[pic actions] 
      (-3pt,0) -- (3pt,0)
      (0,-3pt) -- (0,3pt);
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,dotted] (-5.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,1.9);
\draw[semithick] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[semithick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

\foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}
{
  \draw 
    (\x cm, 1.5pt) -- (\x cm, -1.5pt) node[anchor=north] {\scriptsize $\x$};
  \pic at (\x,0.5) {mycross}; 
  \pic[line width=1pt,red] at (\x,1) {mycross}; 
  \pic[line width=1.5pt,cyan] at (\x,-1) {mycross}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is for some kind of plot, `pgfplots` could be a better choice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymin=-2,
ymax=2,
xmin=-5,
xmax=5,
width=\textwidth,
grid=major,
major grid style=dotted
]
\addplot+[
  mark=+,
  only marks,
  mark size=6pt,
  mark options={line width=3pt}
] 
  coordinates
  {(-4.5,0) (-3,0) (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (2.5,0) (4,0)};
\addplot+[
  mark=+,
  only marks,
  mark size=5pt,
  mark options={line width=2pt},
  mark color=red
] 
  coordinates
  {(-3,1.5) (-2,1.5) (-1,1.5) (0,1.5) (1,1.5) (2,1.5) (2.5,1.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need your `marks` to be like `nodes`, you can use `plot coordinates` command.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,dotted] (-5.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,1.9);
\draw[semithick] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[semithick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

\foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}
    \draw (\x cm, 1.5pt) -- (\x cm, -1.5pt) node[anchor=north] {\scriptsize $\x$};

\draw plot[mark=*, mark options={color=red, scale=1.5}] coordinates { (-5.2,0) (-4.2,0) (-3.2,0) (-2.2,0) (-1.2,0) (-0.2,0)};

\draw plot[mark=+, mark options={color=blue, scale=1.5}] coordinates { (5.2,0) (4.2,0) (3.2,0) (2.2,0) (1.2,0) (0.2,0)};

\draw plot[mark=x, mark options={color=green, scale=1.5}] coordinates { (5.5,0) (4.5,0) (3.5,0) (2.5,0) (1.5,0) (0.5,0)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply to get the idea I only modified 2 lines of your code to produce red crosses on the right axis. You can repeat as you wish.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray,dotted] (-5.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,1.9);
\draw[semithick] (-6,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[semithick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);

\foreach \x in {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5}
    \draw (\x cm, 1.5pt) -- (\x cm, -1.5pt) node[anchor=north] {\scriptsize $\x$};
\fill [radius=2.5pt,color=blue] (-5.2,0) circle[] (-4.2,0) circle[] (-3.2,0) circle[] (-2.2,0) circle[] (-1.2,0) circle[] (-0.2,0) circle;

\foreach \x/\n in {0.1/a,1.1/b,2.1/c,3.1/d,4.1/e,5.1/f}{ % This is what I have added
    \node (\n)[circle,inner sep=2.5pt] at (\x,0){};
    \draw[red] (\n.north west)--(\n.south east)(\n.south west)--(\n.north east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{cross/.style={path picture={
  \draw[red]
    (path picture bounding box.south east)--(path picture bounding box.north west)
    (path picture bounding box.south west)--(path picture bounding box.north east);
}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-2,0)--(2,0);
  \foreach \x in {-1, 0, 1}{
    \node[cross,thick,minimum size=4pt] at (\x,0) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is closer to what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but for some reason, the crosses don't show up on my plot. I have edited the code to include more detail if this helps.

Comment: Also, including the circle overlaps with the axis, making it appear as if there are gaps. I know this is picky but I need it to be just a cross if possible? Thanks

Comment: @user60327 I changed the code now that I understand better what you're trying to do. Hope it works for you.